# Ok so im trying to figure out how to add text to thumbnails (im a complete novice code below)

Tags: javascript, css

To elaborate some things. Im brand spanking new to coding (been at it around a week and a half and still not much further) My problem is im trying to figure out how to set up text underneath my thumbnails as viewed below (That code alone wont make it look right but I figured this is a stupid question with a really easy answer) I need to set a name under each thumbnail and i've been at this for like EVER this isn't copy and pasted code its something i've been grueling over for the last week and this one thing has given me immense problems -_- so far i've been going off the bootstrap page to put all this together but my answer for this hasn't came around yet so I figured i'd ask any idea's?

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="top-listings">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="http://http://www.mp4upload.com/knx8txszxvhc">
                    <img width="80%" style="max-height:10%" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/onepunchman/images/c/c9/One_Punch_Man_TV_Anime_Key_Visual.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150311173301.jpg" alt="Naruto Shippudden" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="http://http://www.mp4upload.com/knx8txszxvhc">
                    <img width="80%" style="max-height:10%" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-sAGd2pCpHgM/Tjr3vGeuPcI/AAAAAAAAAAU/llCHgjsh7Uc/s320/the+law+of+ueki.JPG" alt="Naruto Shippudden" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="http://http://www.mp4upload.com/knx8txszxvhc">
                    <img width="80%" style="max-height:10%" src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140529203802/voiceacting/images/7/7c/Berserk_1997_DVD_Cover.jpg" alt="Naruto Shippudden" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="http://http://www.mp4upload.com/knx8txszxvhc">
                    <img width="80%" style="max-height:10%" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/onepunchman/images/c/c9/One_Punch_Man_TV_Anime_Key_Visual.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150311173301.jpg" alt="Naruto Shippudden" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="http://http://www.mp4upload.com/knx8txszxvhc">
                    <img width="80%" style="max-height:10%" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/onepunchman/images/c/c9/One_Punch_Man_TV_Anime_Key_Visual.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150311173301.jpg" alt="Naruto Shippudden" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="http://http://www.mp4upload.com/knx8txszxvhc">
                    <img width="80%" style="max-height:10%" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/onepunchman/images/c/c9/One_Punch_Man_TV_Anime_Key_Visual.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150311173301.jpg" alt="Naruto Shippudden" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="http://http://www.mp4upload.com/knx8txszxvhc">
                    <img width="80%" style="max-height:100%" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/onepunchman/images/c/c9/One_Punch_Man_TV_Anime_Key_Visual.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150311173301.jpg" alt="Naruto Shippudden" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="http://http://www.mp4upload.com/knx8txszxvhc">
                    <img width="80%" style="max-height:10%" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/onepunchman/images/c/c9/One_Punch_Man_TV_Anime_Key_Visual.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150311173301.jpg" alt="Naruto Shippudden" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>


</div><!-- /.container -->

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="http://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/yhFlDqlSi6BE8L7eU1P8OA/ls.jpg" width="35" height="35" alt="google"  />
                            Copyright &copy; 2015. Powered by Zewa Design. All Rights Reserved.
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

either directly after each `<img>` Tag or before the closing DIV tags of those `col-md-3`DIVs insert a new DIV tag with your text, like

`<div class="my_text">text 1 2 3</div>`

and in your stylesheet, put the desired CSS rules for `.my_text`, like `font-size`, `color`, `text-align: center;` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest form possible you can do this (thi is your first image):

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div>
       <a href="http://http://www.mp4upload.com/knx8txszxvhc">
        <img width="80%" style="max-height:10%" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/onepunchman/images/c/c9/One_Punch_Man_TV_Anime_Key_Visual.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150311173301.jpg" alt="Naruto Shippudden" />
        </a>
     </div>
     <div>
         <span>Image Name Comes here</span>  
     </div>
```

You can additionally style it the way you like.

Comment: Omg THANK YOU -bows- I am not worthy XD That clarifies alot thank you so much!!

Comment: Never Mind. Have a Nice ad Merry Christmas :)